# How to trigger first update with rabbitMQ using rxJava 2.0?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, rx-java, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

Is there an elegant way to subscribe to updates only after I trigger first update of my data using rabbitMQ?
Or.. Is there a way to know when a new consumer is added and trigger sending the data?

For example:

Service A is getting updates from Service B (using rabbitMQ, Service B pushes IPs that I need to send the data to).

Service A is also getting requests from Service C and sends each request to all the IPs from Service B.

My problem is when Service A is up, there might be 1-5 minutes until Service B pushes an update. Meanwhile, Service C can send 100 requests, and I'll have no ips to send these requests ...

If the queue could have known that a new consumer is added - we could trigger sending all the ips..

I hope it explains my problem.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: >`I hope it explains my problem.`

It doesn't.

Comment: Check the combineLatest operator.